# Angular Library Workspace CI/CD and Git tags

Tags: angular, git, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, angular-library

I have an angular workspace that has three libraries in it. What would be the best way of handling CI/CD (Jenkins) for each individual library and tagging releases of each individual library in git?

One idea I had was to make the libraries in the workspace sub-repositories and tag those sub-repositories when there is a new release. If I do it this way then would there be a way of having Jenkins get the workspace repository with the tagged release of the sub-repository that I want to build and deploy?

Does anyone here have experience with this and how do you handle it? I'd like to set this up in a very standard by the books way.